# How does Lazy<T> get around needing new() constraint?

Tags: c#, templates, lazy-evaluation

Example 1 (does not compile):

```
void Main()
{
    var c = new C<D>();
    c.M.F();
}

class C<T>
{
    T _m = null;
    public T M { get {
        if(_m == null) _m = new T();
        return _m; 
    } }
}

class D
{
    public void F() { Console.WriteLine ("i was created"); }
}
```

Result:

> Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint

Example 2 (works):

```
void Main()
{
    var c = new C<D>();
    c.M.F();
}

class C<T>
{
    Lazy<T> _m = new Lazy<T>();
    public T M { get { return _m.Value; } }
}

class D
{
    public void F() { Console.WriteLine ("i was created"); }
}
```

Result:

```
i was created
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you delve into the source code, you'll see that `Lazy<T>` ultimately uses `Activator`:

```
return new Lazy<T>.Boxed((T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)));
```

This is just a shortcut for using reflection.  Since it's not instantiating the type via the actual generic type argument (`new T()`) but rather invoking the constructor through reflection, no `where T : new()` constraint is needed.